# Using Doxygen for existing java code

Tags: java, doxygen

Is it possible to generate documentation from existing java code which will not have Doxygen specific comments and tags. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting the [EXTRACT_ALL](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/starting.html#extract_all) tag in the configuration file to `YES`. From the docs:

> **EXTRACT_ALL**
>
> If the EXTRACT_ALL tag is set to YES doxygen will assume all entities
>   in documentation are documented, even
>   if no documentation was available.
>   Private class members and static file
>   members will be hidden unless the
>   EXTRACT_PRIVATE and EXTRACT_STATIC
>   tags are set to YES